# What does "dairy milk" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

Why is milk called `dairy milk` on this milk carton?

[image: milk carton]

Comment: Because it comes from a dairy? Anyway, the usage of the word milk is a larger issue, as there are other products such as almond milk or soy milk that don't come from cows. Some say these shouldn't be able to use the word "milk" to describe them.

Comment: @user3169 Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the basic reason is because it comes from a dairy.

Anyway, the usage of the word *milk* is a larger issue, as there are other products such as almond milk or soy milk that don't come from cows.

Some "dairy" milk concerns say these products shouldn't be able to use the word *milk* to describe them. Supposedly the "dairy" milk companies don't want to lose market share to the similarly named products, so labeling becomes important.

By definition you can find both cases. See [*milk*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/milk).

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say the milk comes from dairy *animals*, i.e. dairy cows and sometimes dairy goats, regardless of the type of facility where they are milked.

Comment: Couldn't find the word "dairy" on goat's milk products that I checked online, though.

Comment: They are definitely called [dairy goats](http://adga.org/about-dairy-goats/) in the U.S., but the agricultural definition of *dairy* may differ from culinary or economic usages.